# Reducing sample size to change from a paired to unpaired design

Tags: t-test, effect-size, paired-data

I have two groups of data, one consisting of 9 subjects and another consisting of 5 subjects. In the 9 subjects group, 5 of those could be paired with the 5 subjects from the other group. I could run a paired samples t-test and cut out the data for the 4 subjects that cannot be paired or I could run an independent samples t test and completely ignore the paired nature of the data.

I think similar situations have been discussed on this site, but what I want to know is, if I go with the unpaired test instead of the paired test, would the only difference be a loss/change in power? Or in other words, are my results somehow invalid/ suspect if I don't take into account the paired nature of some of the data?

Also I'm wondering if anyone has a good reference for what to do in this kind of situation.

Comment: The change in power depends on the correlation between the outcomes. The higher the correlation, the more worthwhile pairing is. Your sample is pretty small, or I'd suggest a multilevel model or propensity model, that would let you keep everyone.

Comment: You could fit a mixed model and have the best of both worlds (use all data and account for violation of independence). The sample is small but I don't think it's so small that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will definitely keep all of that in mind in the future. I should probably clarify that I'm more interested in what would go wrong or what I would lose if I used an unpaired test on paired data. I am trying to weigh the two options in my head (paired vs unpaired) since, for this project anyway, I'm going to have to use one of the two. I just need some help justifying the decision. For example, if the worst that could happen was a small loss of power by using the unpaired instead of the paired t test, then I could probably live with that.

Comment: @Jimj: As Jeremy Miles said, and as I mentioned in your previous question, pairing influences your expected t-ratio (and hence power) by a factor of $1/\sqrt{1-r}$, with r being the correlation. If $r$ is close to 1, you take a huge hit to power by ignoring pairing. If $r$ is close to 0, you don't lose much at all. So it's hard to make the kind of general statements that you want. That said, I would guess that typically the proportional loss in data from the incomplete pairings would have to be quite severe indeed before this outweighed the power benefit of incorporating the correlation

Comment: @ Jake Westfall:  It sounds then like the only potential issue I have using the unpaired would be a loss of power then, although the actual amount could vary depending on the correlation. Thanks for all of your help clearing this up.

Comment: Any method that discards samples isn't really scientific IMHO.  And the pairing isn't natural in this case.  Were your sample size a bit larger, you could have increased power by blocking.  See randomized block designs.  But never delete observations unless data are demonstrably invalid or irrelevant.  For your sample size I'd use the Wilcoxon test and be done.